# Ocultar menú al pulsar fuera

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, responsive

He visto por ahí un menú responsive sencillo y que quisiera colocar en mi blog, pero no tengo ni idea de javascript y aunque me parece muy mono, veo que es incómodo que no se oculte cuando se hace click fuera de él, o cuando el ratón no esté encima suyo. ¿Alguna solución?

El código original es el publicado en [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp) y es este:

```
 <html> <head> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
 initial-scale=1"> <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <style> body {   margin: 0;   font-family: Arial, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; }

 .topnav {   overflow: hidden;   background-color: #333; }

 .topnav a {   float: left;   display: block;   color: #f2f2f2;  
 text-align: center;   padding: 14px 16px;   text-decoration: none;  
 font-size: 17px; }

 .topnav a:hover {   background-color: #ddd;   color: black; }

 .active {   background-color: #4CAF50;   color: white; }

 .topnav .icon {   display: none; }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {   .topnav a:not(:first-child)
 {display: none;}   .topnav a.icon {
     float: right;
     display: block;   } }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {   .topnav.responsive {position:
 relative;}   .topnav.responsive .icon {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;   }   .topnav.responsive a {
     float: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;   } } </style> </head> <body>

 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">   <a href="#home"
 class="active">Home</a>   <a href="#news">News</a>   <a
 href="#contact">Contact</a>   <a href="#about">About</a>   <a
 href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
     <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>   </a> </div>

 <script> function myFunction() {   var x =
 document.getElementById("myTopnav");   if (x.className === "topnav") {
     x.className += " responsive";   } else {
     x.className = "topnav";   } } </script>

 </body> </html>
```

Comment: Link de W3Schools?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

Comment: Al hacer click, recoge el objeto `event` y busca `event.target` para saber donde se está haciendo click. luego pones la condicion de que sea distinto del area y asi sabes si estás pulsando "fuera"

Comment: Wow, muchas gracias por la respuesta! Desgraciadamente, no sé cómo plasmarlo en código, ya que no tengo ni idea de Javascript... ¿Podrías ayudarme, por favor?

Comment: Investiga lo comentado e intentalo. es muy importante que investigues y pruebes para aprender mejor. nosotros ayudamos con problemas concretos, no tareas. cuando lo hayas intentado, si no te sale, añade a la pregunta tu codigo y el problema especifico que tienes. Un saludo

Comment: Así llevo varios días, créeme... Ufff! Algunos hemos nacido para otras cosas. Gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

He cambiado el código para que funcione con `click`. Lo que hacemos es añadir un evento `onload` para que sea lo primero que se ejecute. En él asignamos al `document`, en el evento `onclick`, la llamada a `myFunction` pasándole el evento (`event`). En `myFunction` comprobamos en qué elemento se ha hecho click. Si se ha hecho click en el menú (fíjate que he puesto dos ids en el `HTML`: `menu` y `menui`) se muestra el menú si no está ya mostrándose, si se está mostrando se oculta. Y si haces `click` fuera del menú también se oculta.

```js
function binding() {
    document.onclick = function(event){
    myFunction(event);
    }
  }

window.onload = binding;
      
function myFunction(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if(e.target.id==="menu" || e.target.id==="menui"){
      if (!x.classList.contains("responsive")){
          x.className += " responsive";
      } 
      else {
          x.className = "topnav";
      }  
    }
    else
    {
      x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .topnav {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }

            .topnav a {
                float: left;
                display: block;
                color: #f2f2f2;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 17px;
            }

                .topnav a:hover {
                    background-color: #ddd;
                    color: black;
                }

        .active {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        }

        .topnav .icon {
            display: none;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
                display: none;
            }

            .topnav a.icon {
                float: right;
                display: block;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav.responsive {
                position: relative;
            }

                .topnav.responsive .icon {
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 0;
                    top: 0;
                }

                .topnav.responsive a {
                    float: none;
                    display: block;
                    text-align: left;
                }
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
 initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#home"
           class="active">Home</a>   <a href="#news">News</a>   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>   <a href="#about">About</a>   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="menu" class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-bars" id="menui"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estoy haciendo pruebas, combinando opciones, y con onmouseover es imposible acceder a los items del menú, jajaja

Comment: Tienes razón XD. Lo cambio.

Comment: Olé, qué crack! Gracias! Estoy intentando también añadirle un onmouseout, para que, además del clik exterior, se oculte solo, pero no me sale, jajaja:
function binding() {
document.onclick = function(event){
myFunction(event);
}
document.onmouseout = function(event){
myFunction(event);
}
}